# Fix fatal error: Index out of range in arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing an issue while importing data from my Firestore database.

Essentially, I'm using the value `index`, which was carried over from a Table View in a previous View Controller as `indexPath?.row`. A fatal error starts when `index` is being used in an array, with the error `fatal error: Index out of range`.

The following code is from this new, redirected View Controller:

```swift
import Firebase

class DetailedSubjectsViewController: UIViewController {

    var index: Int!
    var database: Firestore!
    var subjectsArray = [Subjects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        database = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData()

        let subjects = subjectsArray[index] // fatal error: Index out of range
        labelTitle.text = subjects.name
    }

    func loadData() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        database.collection("users").document(uid ?? "").collection("subjects").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Fatal error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.subjectsArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({ Subjects(dictionary: $0.data())})
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And this is the code from the previous View Controller:

```swift
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let indexPath = tableviewSubjects.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let indexNumber = indexPath?.row
        let detailedSubjectsViewController = segue.destination as! DetailedSubjectsViewController
        detailedSubjectsViewController.index = indexNumber
    }
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You got caught in the *Async-trap*. Add a completion handler.

```
import Firebase

class DetailedSubjectsViewController: UIViewController {

    var index: Int!
    var database: Firestore!
    var subjectsArray = [Subjects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        database = Firestore.firestore()
        loadData() { [weak self] result in
           switch result {
              case .success(let data):
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self?.subjectsArray = data
                     if self?.index < data.count {
                       let subject = data[index]
                       self?.labelTitle.text = subject.name
                     }  
                  }  

              case .failure(let error):
                 fatalError("Fatal error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
           }

        }
    }

    func loadData(completion: @escaping (Result<[Subjects],Error>)->Void) {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        database.collection("users").document(uid ?? "").collection("subjects").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                let subjects = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({ Subjects(dictionary: $0.data())})
                completion(.success(subjects))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, you can add a guard in case this issue happens:

```
database = Firestore.firestore()
loadData()
guard index < subjectsArray.count else { return }
...
```

Next, please note that your loadData() is performing an asynchronous load of the data, this is why you have a callback method that gets called once the data is fully loaded.

Before your callback, the subjectsArray could be empty (and it is!) hence the issue with the out of bound.

```
// let subjects = subjectsArray[index] // fatal error: Index out of range
// labelTitle.text = subjects.name
}

func setSubjectTitle() {
  guard index < subjectsArray.count else { return }
  let subject = subjectsArray[index]
  labelTitle.text = subject.name
}

func loadData() {
  let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
  database
    .collection("users").document(uid ?? "")
    .collection("subjects").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Fatal error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.subjectsArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({ Subjects(dictionary: $0.data())})
                }
                self.setSubjectTitle()
            }
        }
}
```